# Why isn't the height of my div changing when I use a percent value?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the height of my div 75% of the viewport size. When I use a pixel value it adds height to it but when I use a percentage, it appears as a very thin line and doesn't change.

This is my HTML:

```
 <body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="main-wrapper"> </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </body>
```

This is my CSS:

```
 #main-wrapper {
      background-color: blue;
      height: 75%;
 }
```

Comment: try with  75vh   , height can not be given as percentage .. we can set it as view port height

Comment: height can be given as percentage @NuthanKumar but then it will depends on its parent

Comment: Change the height of your container.

Comment: Correct .. as the question is for ViewPort size, in this context it can not be given as percentage

Comment: try to give `row `class height and then try percentage on `main-wrapper `

Comment: Thanks @NuthanKumar I didn't know about "vh" but from my understanding, isn't percentage calculated from the viewport size?

Answer (score 1):

why didn't you specify **width?** ,add the **width**  property to your code to view your div.

```css
html,
body,
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#main-wrapper {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 75%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="main-wrapper">hai</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I didn't think I had to since I specified the column width in the class.

Answer (score 1):

Its not necessary to give width to your div, as it already is a block element. All you need to do is specify the height of its parent.

In this case it could be the `row` or the `body` element.

```css
html,
body,
.container-fluid,
.row {
  height: 100%;
}
#main-wrapper {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 75%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="main-wrapper">hai</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note: It is not recommended to use percentage height on a parent which is unfixed, might cause design issues.

Also if you are using a standard framework, don't edit the default CSS for this purpose, add your own `class` or `id` for manipulating its height

Answer (score 0):

As @NuthanKumar mentioned already, you can use `vh` which means viewport height instead of `%`.

Here's an example:

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

If you're having trouble with the width, use `vw` which means viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

See the mistake you are making is that you are giving 75% height to #main-wrapper. #main-wrapper is child of .row div so it will take it's 75% height. 
Since .row height is 0 so 75% of 0 will be 0.
You need to either specify #main-wrapper height in pixel or
viewport height as you want the height to be 75% of viewport.
So following will be the css code:

```
#main-wrapper {
  height: 75vh;
}
```

Hope this helps )